# How to search using company name with the Search for users (v2) connector

Tags: power-automate

How can I search by company name using Search for Users(v2) connector, the Search term does not allow search by name, also the default limit is 1000 how to increase limit for record?

[image]

It says Search String applies to display name, given name, surname, mail, mail nickname and user principle name?

What are ways to increase limit and include other filters?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [list users](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/graph/users/list?view=azure-devops-rest-7.1&tabs=HTTP) method of the Graph API for this with a $filter on companyName.

Below is an example with the HTTP action.

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$filter=companyName eq '@{variables('CompanyName')}'&$select=companyName,id,displayName&$count=true
```

Don't forget to add the **ConsistencyLevel: eventual** header to your HTTP request.

[image]

Comment: This is premium connector also want to connect as profile not using active directory Auth

Comment: The non-premium HTTP request actions are all pretty limited in what type of resources they are allowed to use in the URI field. For example the Send an HTTP request action (of Office 365 Users connector) does allow the users resource, however it also requires a second object like messages,mailFolders,events,calendar,calendars,outlook,inferenceClassification. Alternatively, you could retrieve all your users and use a Filter Array action to filter afterwards.